# Text Is Not Aligning Properly In HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

Hello there I want to include a blog post card in my website, and I want the text to be under each other but even after I set `text:align: justify;` it still does not work. Why?

My HTML/CSS of the card:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.container1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 80px;
}

.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     }


.square{
  width: 460px;
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

.mask{
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

img1{
  width: 460px;
  }

.h11{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p9{
 text-align: justify; 
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #C8C8C8;
 line-height: 18px;
}

.button56 {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
```

```html
 <section>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/blog.css">  
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask">
     <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
        <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>
        
     <div><a href="https://medium.com/@laheshk/is-apple-a-design-company-f5c83514e261" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      </div>
      
</section>
```

Ignore the image from the output above but as you can see, my text is not formatted properly and I tried everything I could to make it work, but I can't.

---

Expected Output:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 80px;
}

.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     }


.square{
  width: 460px;
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

.mask{
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

img{
  width: 460px;
  }

.h1{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p{
 text-align: justify; 
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #C8C8C8;
 line-height: 18px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 90px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog card</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask">
     <div class="h1">Is Apple a Design Company?</div>
        <p>Apple is more than a tech company; it became a culture unto itself, a passion of most of people and the birthplace of the world’s most revolutionized products.</p>
        
     <div><a href="https://medium.com/@laheshk/is-apple-a-design-company-f5c83514e261" target="_" class="button">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      </div>
```

Again ignore the image from the above output, but I want my text to be formatted like that. How would I do that?

Comment: Note, you can't just make up your own HTML elements like `p9`. [You have to do more work](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a left and right `padding` of 30px to your `.p9` class plus apply `display: block` to it to have the same padding as in the header above it. (BTW: You should also apply `padding: right` to the `.h11` class, otherwise your text might go to far to the right if the text content, font-size or container width changes.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 80px;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
  width: 460px;
  height: 430px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

img1 {
  width: 460px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}
```

```html
<section>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/blog.css">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="square">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask">
      <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
      <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

      <div><a href="https://medium.com/@laheshk/is-apple-a-design-company-f5c83514e261" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
    </div>



  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

look my friend, give your p not p9 class or make your style p directly with the style on the expected output.

```
p{
 text-align: justify; 
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #C8C8C8;
 line-height: 18px;
```

}

that's all

don't forget to change `<p9>` to `<p>`

Comment: I changed it to p9 because I already had p used in my other css file, and I dont want to override it with it

Comment: Try to change it into `<div>` and add a class for it and copy past your style